# Shell script- To fetch the content from the specific tag at all occurrence using shell scripting

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have an XML file on my server. In that file, I have many tags in which there is a tag for example, "container" tag.
I need to fetch the content of all the container tags content separately. Many thanks in advance.

[image: Problem statement with expected output]

Comment: Would you mind providing an example file that we can copy? You can just paste the example from your image into some code marks (``)

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: @eike  --> Please find below the example code with expected output

{
<xyz>
 <data> </data>
</xyz>

<Container abc="value" pqr="value" />

<tag1 attribute="value" />

<Container mno="value"  def="value" />


## Expected output
1. abc="value" pqr="value"
2. mno="value"  def="value"

}

Comment: 1) Please edit the question to insert the text example. It's not useful in a comment. 2) Can a `Container` tag be split over two or more lines? 3) Can there be more than one `Container` tag in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the most trival case, no line break inside the tag and no two `Container` tags in the same line,

```
sed -n 's_.*<Container \([^>]*\) />.*_\1_p' filename
```

is supposed to give you the desired output.

- The `s` command substitutes a pattern with a replacement
- `.*<Container` matches the whole line upto the beginning of your tag. You want to remove that.
- `[^>]*` matches any number of characters except `>` (this is to prevent catching more than one tag). This is the part you want to keep, so it is surrounded by `\(\)` so we can use it in the replacement as `\1`
- `/>.*` is the rest of the line you want to throw away
- `\1` in the replacement stands for the part that was matches by the first pair of `\(\)`, so this is what you want to print
- The `p` prints the output in case of a match, while other output is suppressed by the `-n` option

If it's getting more complicated, I suggest to use a specialized XML tool or an XML parsing library for `python` for example.

Comment: Thank you for your support